# Как организовать слаженную работу опытной команды frontend разработчиков?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, gulp, frontend, webpack

В команде работают пять разработчиков, все опытные и ответственные люди, но понимание основ и фундамента проекта у каждого своё. Приведу пример:

- одна часть команды "рвёт" вперёд: использует вебпак как сборщик, даже на рядовых корпоративных сайтах, даже на одностраничниках, постоянно заморачивается с конфигами, линтерами, прекоммитерами и всякой ернудой. Использует бабель, css гриды с "фолбеком" на флекс боксы и прочую, так сказать, хай-энд ерунду. Шаблонизирует все что можно и нельзя на `vue.js` (к примеру, табы, аккордионы и тд). Да, тратит на это ресурсы и время, но вроде как "современненько".
- другая часть более "консервативна": использует стандартный гульповый конфиг, с компилятором и минификатором `scss` и `js`, `jquery`, проверенные годами плагины и свои наработки. Совсем НЕ использует `const,let,forEach[...nodeSelector]` и тд и не хотят использовать. Всё работает стабильно, легко и дешево поддерживается, работает быстро. Но вроде как "не современно".

Клиентам без разницы, менеджерам без разницы, page speed высокий у каждой команды, в целом верстка и фронт качественный.

Всё бы хорошо, но когда одной команде нужно поддерживать другую - возникают проблемы, вторая считает что вебпак это муть (но это и правда муть ещё та), у первой глаза текут от `$` и `EcmaScript 2005` (что тоже наверно и правда устарело).

Не увольняться же хорошим разработчикам? Господа, дайте совет как поступить правильно!

Comment: Ну так очевидно - жестко задать общие правила для группы. Использовать везде более-менее один стек, код-стайл, завести стандартные конфиги линтера, jquery запретить. А тех кто ES6 не учит - на мороз)

Comment: Так-ли нужен es6 для "пары слайдеров и аккордеона"?

Comment: для слайдеров и аккордеона не нужен, а для разработчика - необходим

Comment: Так хотелось бы пояснений, почему он необходим? Если пятого хватает за глаза, а шестой работает только через костыли (babel)

Comment: @Darth почему jQuery запретить?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, у jQuery есть [фатальный недостаток](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: @Darth, ES6 старье уже, 8 редакция уже почти год как

Comment: @ferrari, последние версии браузеров нормально поддерживают фишки вроде `const,let,forEach[...nodeSelector]`

Comment: @Grundy, дело не в браузерах, а в голове разраба. разве `$('.nodeClass').each();` не удобнее спред операторов?

Comment: @ferrari, конечно удобнее, ведь спреад оператор не применим к обычному объекту, которым является jquery объект :-) Тем более spread оператор никак не связан с `each` и если уж сравнивать spread оператор, то только с вызовом `apply`

Comment: @ferrari. хотя вру, в последних версиях применим :)

Comment: Автор поста видимо относится к группе консерваторов. Вообще новый синтаксис, новые возможности, новые фреймворки надо изучать и применять. Иначе через 2-3 года разработчики-консерваторы с удивлением обнаружат, что совсем не понимают, как работает современный фронтенд. Конечно, простые сайты можно писать с использованием jquery, в верстке применять table. Но подумайте о будущем.

Comment: Поэтому консерваторов - переучивать, заставлять использовать новые технологии. Ведь подумайте, когда-то и gulp был новой фишкой, облегчающей жизнь.